# How do I prove that a tensor is the sum of its symmetric and antisymmetric parts?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$, $\mathcal{J}^k(V)$ be the set of k-tensors over $V$, $\Lambda^k(V)$ the set of anti-symmetric k-tensors over $V$ and $S^k(V)$ the set of symmetric k-tensors over $V$.

My teacher asserted that $\mathcal{J}^k(V)=S^k(V)\oplus \Lambda^k(V)$.

I haven't been able to prove this. I

tried to see if a tensor $H\in\mathcal{J}^k(V)$ could be written as the sum of its $Alt(H)$ and $Sym(H)$ but this failed. I realized this could only be done for $k=2$. In what other way would it be sensible to attempt to write an arbitrary tensor as a unique sum of a anti-symmetric tensor and a symmetric tensor?

Thanks!

Comment: Dimension counting works if $V$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: Another idea: the symmetrization operator is linear.  What is its kernel?

Comment: I have to proof later that the $kerSym=\Lambda^k(V)$ so I don't think I need that for the proof. Does the theorem work for infinite dimensional V?

Comment: The claim is wrong, at least if the meaning of "antisymmetric" is the standard one. The standard definition has nothing to do with the kernel of the symmetrization map!